# Do ghosts only appear before the Apocalypse?

Tags: ghostbusters

In both Ghostbuster movies they prevent the Apocalypse. In one by a god (Gozer) and in the other by a magician (Vigo the Carpathian). In the first movie they are ridiculed for believing and studying the paranormal until ghosts actually start to appear. In the second they are no longer busting ghosts until the ectoplasm causes ghosts to appear.

In the [second film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostbusters_II) it states that they were sued for property damage and given a restraining order, but later in the movie as soon as ghosts do start showing up they are able to start up business again. So I'm asking does it take the end of the world for ghosts to appear?

Comment: Well, ghosts can't show up *after* the end of the world, as there'd be nowhere to show up, so if they're going to show up at all, it's got to be before.

Comment: The end of the world sees more of them wandering around, but they're there regardless...which is why they were studying them to begin with. As for the second movie, it's not so much the lack of ghosts as it is a lack of money that sends the business under. Unless my memory is totally faulty, both situations are explained to some degree in the movies. The real question is what made them quit smoking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Depending on what counts as an Apocalypse, no, it is not necessary

In *[Extreme Ghostbusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_Ghostbusters)* Egon's gang of new Ghostbusters is formed without any sign of apocalypse. They are assembled when [Achira](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Achira) is accidentally released from her imprisonment. Nothing explicitly to do with an apocalypse.

Also, the apocalypse is not implicit with the return of [Vigo the Carpathian](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Vigo) (Ghostbusters II), but that is certainly a possible eventuality if left unchecked. In the [video game](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Ghostbusters:_The_Video_Game) his portrait says "I see the evil of the times to come. *Millennial apocalypse*! Your world unravels...maybe. Maybe not." (emphasis mine) so not even he is sure about the apocalypse!).

The apocalypse however seemed to be [Ivo Shador](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Ivo_Shandor)'s intent, with the (eventual) summoning of Gozer the Gozerian (Ghostbuster's I). Do note, that the [Mood Slime](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Psychomagnotheric_Slime) form the sequel is ultimately also [Ivo Shador]'s doing, but it's origin is only incidental to [Vigo](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/Vigo)'s awakening.

In conclusion, I would say that the events often associated with apocalypses may fuel the psychic energy needed for ghostly manifestations (as seen in the first movie), but I don't think it's strictly required, and ultimately something else is often at work that then leads to an apocalyptic scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the the wiki (link below) about "The Real Ghostbusters" it does not seem that every week they were going to try and destroy life as we know it. So I would say it doesn't take the end of the world for ghosts to appear but I would say it probably helps to see large numbers everywhere.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Real_Ghostbusters